# What is wrong with this attempt to serve up static content? Does a Proxy/ReverseProxy trump Alias, or can I ask for Alias to trump proxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, django

I'm working on getting Apache to serve up static files for a Django project. My VirtualHost has:

```
Alias /static/ /home/jonathan/pragmatometer/static/

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```

But requests for /static/css/style.css are being served by the Django process, not a static pull to /home/jonathan/pragmatometer/static/css/style.css.

What can I do so that the Alias trumps the proxy? I can try to cobble together several ProxyPass / ProxyPassReverse definitions for /load/, /save/, /admin/, but that has got to be the wrong way.

So what's the right way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `ProxyPass` wins in that case.  The way to avoid this problem is:

```
ProxyPass /static/ !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
```